# saving parts of xml object as object

Tags: php, xml

I created an xml file that stores some information for me. Now I want to get elements that meet some conditions.

At the moment this looks like this:

```
Function getElements($xmlObject, $name){

    foreach($xmlObject->feature as $feature){

    if(stristr($feature->path, $name))){    
     array_push($aSubFeatures, $feature);

    }
    }

    return $obj;
}
```

But I'd prefer getting an object as a return value. I used simpleXML for getting the xml file as an object.

I also tried using DOM (creating new DOMDocument and tried to append the gotten feature element objects) but without reasonable result.

Would deleting all not matching parts of the xml a solution? Did not found a way to delete special elements...

Thanks for your help

Comment: This question is pretty vague. Can you provide a more in-depth explanation of what you are trying to achieve? Maybe also add an example showing the desired input and output.

Comment: hmm. I only want to get some of the elements in that xml file. Currently I can choose between all elements of that xml as one big object or parts of the xml object saved in an array. What I would like to have is a new xml object only containing the searched elements.

Answer (score 0):

For appending an element of a current existing DOMDocument into a new DOMDocument you have to call [`$newdom->importNode($nodeInOldDOM)`](http://es.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php). You cannot do a regular appendChild of a node from another document.